# Load distinct record in crystal report

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

In my SQL database table i have record like

```
EmpID(int-pk) | Attend-Date(datetime) |workinghrs(time(0))|extrahrs(time(0))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1         |   15-04-2015          |  04:10:30          |01:00:00
    1         |   16-04-2015          |  02:10:30          |02:00:00
    1         |   17-04-2015          |  04:50:30          |04:00:00
    2         |   18-04-2015          |  01:40:00          |01:40:00
    2         |   14-04-2015          |  06:10:00          |00:40:00
```

Now i need to select this record between date range from 14-04-2015 to 18-04-2015 but with sum of workinghrs and extrahrs against each EmpID

something like this

```
EmpID(int-pk) | |workinghrs (time(0)) |extrahrs(time(0))
 ------------------------------------------------------
   1          |11:20:30               |07:00:00
   2          |07:50:00               |02:20:00
```

Then i have to show all this on crystal report. I am using c# windows app and on this issue i have no idea how to build a logic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the logic of query? If yes this will give the result

```
  select EmpID ,sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', workinghrs ))
 ,sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', extrahrs ))
  from <table>
  group by EmpID
  Order by EmpId
```